# How can i access the files in a vmdk file?

Tags: debian, vmware

I had problems with the virtual machines, I wanted to know if there is a way to access the virtual disk files, I had heard about OSFMount but it does not give me access to the folder I need

restore the backup of the virtual machine on the host so that the system was running, but I need to get the data that is inside the disk, I have it on an external disk, it moved it to a Windows computer, then CentOS to be able to access with vmware-mount but it sends me an error "Failed to mount disk 'SERVER-04.Palmiss.local.vmdk': It is not safe to mount the virtual disk. It may be in use."

Comment: Is this 1 vmdk file or was the disk split into several files?

Comment: it is a single vmdk file

Comment: Okay, so is this a desktop host with something like vmware player installed? I ask because if you have already downloaded vmware player to your Linux host the solution should be rather straightforward. Please edit your post to elaborate more on the exact setup. Thank you.

Comment: No, restore the backup of the virtual machine on the host so that the system was running, but I need to get the data that is inside the disk, I have it on an external disk, it moved it to a Windows computer, then CentOS to be able to access with vmware-mount but it sends me an error "Failed to mount disk 'SERVER-04.Palmiss.local.vmdk': It is not safe to mount the virtual disk.  It may be in use."

Answer (score 12):

There are several methods to gain access to a `vmdk` file.

#### vmware-mount

As you have already tried there is `vmware-mount`. Make sure you are entering all the correct commands when using it. I have referenced [this site](http://www.jameslittle.me.uk/how-to-mount-vmdk-files-in-linux/) for information about `vmware-mount`. This link is dated, however it may still apply to you.

It might be necessary to only mount the specific parition or to know the correct partition number in your case.

```
vmware-mount -p #list partitions
mkdir /mnt/vmdkfile #create a mountpoint for your file
vmware-mount /path/to/vmfile.vmdk 1 /mnt/vmdkfile
```

Note that the `1` is the correct partition number listed out in the `vmware-mount -p` command. This may not work as in your case `vmware-mount` is complaining that the disk is still in use. If possible you can use VMWare Player or Workstation to attempt to create a new VM using your `.vmdk` as the disk. Alternatively, you can try `QEMU`.

#### QEMU

If you need only read-only access QEMU can mount `.vmdk` files. I am referencing [this Stack Exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327728/mounting-vmdk-disk-image) for this part.

Verify that you have the `nbd` kernel module.

```
sudo modprobe nbd
```

Mount the vmware disk file to `nbd`.

```
sudo qemu-nbd -r -c /dev/nbd1 ./path/to/vmfile.vmdk
```

Then mount it to your Linux host using the following:

```
mount /dev/nbd1p1 /mnt
```

However this might not be in a usable format for you. In which case I recommend you try to extract the contents of the file using `7zip`. For these last couple of options I have referenced [this site](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/extract-content-vmdk-files-step-step-guide/).

#### 7zip

Verify that you can list the contents of the file using `7zip`.

```
7z l vmfile.vmdk
```

If you can and you do see relevant directories then you should be able to extract specific files with the following:

```
7z e vmfile.vmdk FILE
```

This will extract FILE from the `.vmdk`. You can `grep` through the `.vmdk` to find specific files if you need to. If you require the whole disk simply using `7z e vmfile.vmdk` should extract the whole archive.

#### /dev/loop and guestmount

You can use a loop device or even `guestmount` to also attempt to mount the image.

List the current loop devices with `fdisk -l | grep /dev/loop` or `df -h | grep /dev/loop`.

If your loop devices go up to 20 then create a higher numbered loop device and mount your image with:

```
losetup /dev/loop30 /path/to/vmfile.vmdk
```

The [link](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/extract-content-vmdk-files-step-step-guide/) I mentioned earlier talks about making an offset but that should only be necessary for specific Windows VMs.

There is also a Linux utility called `guestmount`. Read more about it [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/guestmount) on its manpage. Check out the examples from it here:

> For a typical Windows guest which has its main filesystem on the first partition:
>
> ```
> guestmount -a windows.img -m /dev/sda1 --ro /mnt
> ```
>
> For a typical Linux guest which has a /boot filesystem on the first partition, and the root filesystem on a logical volume:
>
> ```
> guestmount -a linux.img -m /dev/VG/LV -m /dev/sda1:/boot --ro /mnt
> ```
>
> To get libguestfs to detect guest mountpoints for you:
>
> ```
> guestmount -a guest.img -i --ro /mnt
> ```

#### Conclusion

For your reference I will also include a link to VMWare documentation on [.vmdk mounting restrictions](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vddk.utils.doc_50/diskutils_mount.4.2.html). Please read over all the links I have provided before trying any of the commands. If a specific one worked the best for you, I can limit the scope of this post. If you have any questions or there are any misconceptions or issues in my post please comment and I can make edits as necessary.

Best of Luck!

Comment: What an awesome answer! Thanks!